# Firebase Android chat like XMPP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a firbase chat application.
Using Firbase console i have gone through all basic stuffs like Create Users, send One to One Messaging, store and retrieve from firebase realtime database.
My Question is : 
I want to develop a chat app like xmpp using firebase.
That means i want all functionality like users presense , is typing indication and send Notification while users are neither in background nor in the app.

I have tried using google but not getting proper result.
So if anyone know about this then please help me to any reference link or provide any idea how to achieve this.

I have used this link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Thanking you.

Comment: Define "proper result" ... also *any reference link or provide any idea* ... well, ***Questions asking us to** recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow***

Comment: I am able to authenticate users and read write data to and from firebase real time database.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users
This is the link which  i used to authenticate firebase user.
I want presense of listed users in my account.

Comment: As you've written it, the question is way too broad. If you're having trouble with a concrete step in there (such as getting the [presence detection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) working), post the minimal code that reproduces that problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I got the presence of current user but i am not able to get the presence of all registered users while retrieve user from Firebase database.

Comment: If you're having trouble making your code work, post the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen i have used below code snippet to check the status of login user but how i can get the presence of a user with whom i chat.

final DatabaseReference connectedRef = database.getReference(".info/connected");

and use connected reference listner.